# Unable to get text from span using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium and python to scrape and control a website. I am able to get all the other span text from the site but unable to grab this specific one. I've searched to the end of the internet trying to find a solution with no luck.

Here is the snippet of what I am trying to grab:

```
    <td style="width:15%;"></td><td colspan="3" style="width:100%;"><span id="WebSplitter1_tmpl1_ContentPlaceHolder1_eMessage" style="color:Red;">The Date Range allowed is '90 Days Before' Today plus Tomorrow, but Tomorrow's data only after 5:00 PM Today.</span></td>
</tr>
```

This is on the same page just next to the element I am trying to grab and works as expected:

```
    </tbody></table></td><td style="width:25%;"><span id="WebSplitter1_tmpl1_ContentPlaceHolder1_lCapEffTm" class="bodytext">Eff Time:  09:00 CCT</span></td><td style="width:30%;"></td>
</tr><tr>
```

My code:

elem = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='WebSplitter1_tmpl1_ContentPlaceHolder1_eMessage']")

for i in elem:
print(i.text)

This will works fine to grab the span above it (ending in lCapEffTm) and returns, "Eff Time:  09:00 CCT" as expected. The other span (ending in eMessage) is the only one that is giving me issues on the page.

Comment: Depends what you want here. If you want all of the ones that start with that xpath use [@id*='WebSplitter1_tmpl1_ContentPlaceHolder1_eMessage']. You can also just grab the WebSplitter1_tmpl1_ContentPlaceHolder1_lCapEffTm for the id seperately.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm just looking to grab the one ending in eMessage. I was trying to explain that I know my code works for some spans but I can't get it to work on the one eMessage span. Sorry I wasn't clear.